# jquery find childs and not grand childs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all the childs div and ignore grand childs divs using a jQuery Selector, I have this as example:

```js
$('.main').find('.this').show(); // shows the first only
```

```css
div.this{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
      <div>
        ... a lot of more divs levels ...
        <div>
          <div class='this'>show this!!!!!!!!!!
            <div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='this'>show this!!!!!!!!!!
            <div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to select "this" elements on the first level found, but don't search deeper, so none of the following codes work:

```
$('.main').find('.this').show(); // shows them all
$('.main').find('.this').show(); // select both
$('.main').find('.this').eq(0).show(); // shows the first only
$('.main').find('.this').first().show(); // shows the first only
$('.main .this:nth-child(1)').show(); // shows the first only and his childs
$('.main').find('.this').siblings().show(); // doesn't show anything
$('.main > div > div > .this').show(); // we don't know how deep level is
$('.main').children('.this').show(); // we don't know how deep level is
$('.main').closest('.this').show(); // looks up through its ancestors only
```

Testing all the answers

```
// Kevin B
$('.main').find('.this').first().siblings('.this').addBack().show() // it works, I don't know how!
// Alexander Solonik
$('.main').find('.this').eq(0).siblings('.this').addBack().show() // this one also works, why!?
```

It is possible to limit how many levels I want to find?

Comment: .first() will serve your purpose. it will, as you can probably guess, reduce the list of found elements to the first one. if it's a direct child, it'l be that one, if it's 3 levels deep, it'l be that one, etc.

Comment: Thank you, `.first()` will select the first child only, I want to select all the childs in the first level found.

Comment: Once you have the first, you can use .siblings to find it's... siblings. There's plenty of traversal methods at your disposal.

Comment: @stramin check my edited answer .. let me know if its what your looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to find the first level of elements though, which are not direct decedents, you can use a combination of `find()`, `eq()`, `siblings()`, and `addBack()` to get the first level of elements.

```js
$('.main').find('.this').eq(0).siblings('.this').addBack().show()
```

```css
div.this {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    ... a lot of more divs levels ...
    <div>
      <div class='this'>show this!!!!!!!!!!
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class='this'>do not show this
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class='this'>do not show this
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='this'>show this!!!!!!!!!!
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class='this'>do not show this
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class='this'>do not show this
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, We don't know how deep is the first div, so, I don't know how many `.children('div')` I have to write.

Comment: @stramin check the edit , adding explanation shortly !

Comment: What does this answer have to do with `.children()`? You're not even using it.

Comment: @gforce301 had kept that as a reference note .. after i realized that, the OP's elements that needed to be found were not direct decedents of the parent element

Comment: Sorry... i didn't realize you already had the same answer. Not quite sure how i missed that

Comment: It works for me, but I don't know why, I am reading something about addBack(), thank you!

Comment: @KevinB haha no problem dude :P happens

Comment: @stramin, glad to help , if you found the answer helpful , accept any of the answers

Answer (score 2):

.find, .first, .siblings, and .addBack will get you the results you want.

```
$('.main').find('.this').first().siblings('.this').addBack().show()
```

it'll find the first `.this`, find siblings that have the class, add the previous selection back to the collection, and then show them.

```js
$('.main').find('.this').first().siblings('.this').addBack().show()
```

```css
div.this{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
      <div>
        ... a lot of more divs levels ...
        <div>
          <div class='this'>show this!!!!!!!!!!
            <div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='this'>show this!!!!!!!!!!
            <div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class='this'>do not show this
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works for me, but I don't know why, I am reading something about addBack(), thank you!